# Question posting style

Tags: support, questions, posting

I joined Stack Overflow in January. Until now, I was very satisfied with this website. I was getting proper responses when posting questions out there.

But for the last week, I am not getting any responses at all. I posted 3 questions but didn't get any reply...

Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for the same.. why I am not getting any response..
even my answer rate is proper, it's around 74%...

Answer (score 15):

Looking at your [recent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576050/abbas), I see:

- sorting in gridview [gridview](/questions/tagged/gridview)[sorting](/questions/tagged/sorting)
- storing stored procedure in dataset [stored-procedures](/questions/tagged/stored-procedures)[dataset](/questions/tagged/dataset)[multiple-resultsets](/questions/tagged/multiple-resultsets)
- disable dropdownlist items [dropdownlist](/questions/tagged/dropdownlist)[disable](/questions/tagged/disable)[listitem](/questions/tagged/listitem)
- Calling multiple values in Function Parameter [function](/questions/tagged/function)[parameters](/questions/tagged/parameters)[multiple](/questions/tagged/multiple)[values](/questions/tagged/values)
- working on TFS 2010 [server](/questions/tagged/server)[team](/questions/tagged/team)[foundation](/questions/tagged/foundation)[issues](/questions/tagged/issues)

These are some of the worse use of tags I've seen for some time.

First, of all, the last one should be [tfs](/questions/tagged/tfs). You can leave off "issues" - it's assumed you have issues, or you wouldn't have asked the question. You might have tried [team-foundation-server](/questions/tagged/team-foundation-server). You should use "-" between words of a single tag, not spaces.

Second, most of your questions say nothing about what technology you're using, neither in the titles, nor in the tags. How should anyone know you're asking ASP.NET questions if you don't tell them?

Answer (score 8):

I've edited your questions to improve the wording and improved the tags.  Here are some tips:

- If they have a language associated with them (for ASP.NET, you either want the solution in C# or VB.NET) then you should add that to the tags.
- Post Code. Post Code. Post Code.  If you aren't posting the code that you have a question about, no one will be able to help you until you post it.  **Show, don't tell.**
- Leave off the salutations.

Answer (score 5):

You should have your answers tagged correctly. Probably almost nobody notices your questions. (As you can see you have very low number of `views` on those questions - 11-15) Try adding more popular tags, at least one. For example something like `wpf`, `asp.net` or whatever framework/technology you use.